# Facebook Live Stream Widget Statistics

Tags: facebook, widget

We are using Facebook's Live Stream widget to go alongside a live video stream.  Worked well but I am trying to find out how many wall posts/status updates were made through the widget during the event.

The live stream widget does have a FB App that goes along with it, but do see any app statistics that seem to connect to users posting through the widget.

Any Live Stream Widget users out there have any insight into getting meaningful and basic data about usage out?

Answer (score 0):

"**The Live Stream plugin will be removed on September 5, 2012**" ~ Facebook team

I recommend you use comments box instead.

*[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/06/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)*